# Wrapping an animation around an object

Tags: animation, uv, objects, parent

I want to wrap the 3D animation of gears turning around a sphere while the sphere glows on and off. Will the wrap modifier work? If so, how?

Comment: Hello, could you please explain more in details what you mean by "wrap the 3D animation"? Maybe show some pictures...

Comment: Try do it with shape keys I'm not sure if it's possible though.

Comment: @moonoots: the user wants to animate 3D gears **on the surface** of a UV sphere, like this >> https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a68r9z2amgd8tq/Scena_Abstrakcja4%5BHD%2B%5D2.jpg?dl=0